# Effect of Charon on Pluto

Tags: solar-system, natural-satellites, pluto, charon

Even though Pluto is not known as a planet anymore, theroetically it has/had a moon, called Charon. I've heard about something that their size are so close to each other that while Charon rotates around Pluto, it also rotates around a central point.

How does it work exactly?

Comment: Of course, it also has Styx, Hydra, Nix and Kerberos - which also have an effect, just a much smaller one.

Comment: @RoryAlsop Never heard of them. My knowledge is a bit old maybe

Comment: Has a moon, or five. In 1994 a smaller asteroid was found orbiting a lsrger one, and ever since a "moon" does not have to orbit a "planet". So Charon (and now, others) is a moon of Pluto, period.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mathematically, the motion of the Pluto-Charon system can be decomposed into two parts: The motion of Pluto-Charon about the Sun, and the motion of Pluto and Charon about one another. If one sets the reference point to be the center of Pluto, the path the Pluto-Charon system would appear to follow about the Sun would be an [epicycle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deferent_and_epicycle), which is a far more complicated means of describing the pair's trajectory through space. By instead setting this reference point to be the [barycenter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinates_%28astronomy%29), the trajectory followed by the Pluto-Charon system is conveniently a Keplerian ellipse.

Charon is 11.6% the mass of Pluto, and is (on average) 19,571 km away from Pluto (Source [1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluto), [2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charon_%28moon%29)). The barycenter is the point at which the masses of the two bodies "balance", and for the Pluto-Charon system it lies at a distance of $$\frac{m_{\text{Charon}}}{m_{\text{Pluto}}+m_{\text{Charon}}}\times\text{distance}=\frac{0.116}{1.116}\times\text{distance}=0.104\times 19,571\,\text{km}=2,034\,\text{km}$$ from the center of Pluto. As Pluto is only 1,153 km in radius, the barycenter lies ~900 km above its surface. The Pluto-Charon system is the only known (minor or major) planet for which this is the case, although the Earth-Moon system will likely satisfy this criteria billions of years in the future (see [Is the Moon a Planet?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/26304/is-the-moon-a-planet) on Physics SE). There are some instances of [binary asteroids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_asteroid), however, for which the barycenter lies outside the surface of both bodies.

Comment: The IAU needs to update the dwarf planet list to include Charon so we can start officially calling the Pluto-Charon system a binary dwarf planet system.

Comment: @called2voyage so very true, and I would imagine that Pluto-Charon are not even remotely the only one.