# What theories are there in explaining the formation of the Pluto-Charon system?

Tags: pluto, charon, formation

After reading the question and answer to [Effect of Charon on Pluto](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/424/effect-of-charon-on-pluto), a further question is this: how is the Pluto-Charon relationship explained?

Specifically, what theories are there in how did the Pluto-Charon system was formed?

Additionally, does this explain the presence of other moons (Nix, Hydra etc)?

Answer (score 3):

The favored theory is a giant impact, at the end of the final stage of planetary formation ([Canup, 2005](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2005Sci...307..546C)). A "giant impact" is a collision with an object of a comparable size of the planet. That is also the most probable scenario for lunar formation ([Canup, 2004](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2004ARA%26A..42..441C)).